# Posting Islamic remainders on social media

Tags: quran, sharia

Can we post Islamic remainder on Instagram Valid if the post are copied from other pages

Answer (score 0):

Salam. No problem in that till the post is beneficial,contains authentic knowledge and nothing in the post is against islam and its teachings and you must also look for copyright issue if there are any. Allah says in  the Quran: "And who is better in speech than one who invites to Allah and does righteousness and says, "Indeed, I am of the Muslims." (41:33)
So we should continue calling people towards Islam in the best possible ways.